# Add a new column to a numpy array with values based on list of indices

Tags: arrays, numpy

Having an original numpy array like:

```py
a = np.array([
    [12, 43],
    [42, 23],
    [33, 22],
    [53, 15],
    [34, 31]
])
```

I want to add a new column to `a` based on an array of indices:

```py
indices = np.array([2, 3])
```

such that `a` becomes:

```py
# if index is in "indices", new value is 1, otherwise 0

a = np.array([
    [12, 43, 0],
    [42, 23, 0],
    [33, 22, 1],
    [53, 15, 1],
    [34, 31, 0]
])
```

Note: I cannot use Pandas in this context, it has to be a pure numpy solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new `nx1` zeros array and assign `indices` location to `1` and `column_stack`

```
b = np.zeros((a.shape[0],1))
b[indices] = 1
c = np.column_stack([a, b])

Out[28]:
array([[12., 43.,  0.],
       [42., 23.,  0.],
       [33., 22.,  1.],
       [53., 15.,  1.],
       [34., 31.,  0.]])
```